# How to access JSON sent in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: node.js, json, http

I am making a post request to an endpoint which calls stripes charge API endpoint, however each time that I do i get the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0 
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:19662:51)
```

Is there any way that I can access the JSON/XMLHttpRequest directly

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your json object/file you're trying to send

Comment: We need more information. Can you show how you're making the `POST` request and what the `body` value is?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the Post request is done using  environment variables, it looks like this "this.http.post(`${environment.BASE_API_URL}/charge`,t ); " and the body value is just a stripe card object.

Comment: If the failing request is made from you browser to your API, you should be able to inspect it using e.g. chrome developer tools. From there you can see the request body and the response. Most other browsers have similra features, but here is link to chromes: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: is it your code doing the `JSON.parse` on the server side? If so, look the value of the parameter used. It very likely starts with a 'g' so isn't JSON. Knowing the string's value will be a clue at what has gone wrong.